# AKS AGIC: Readiness probe failed: Get "http://192.168.0.12:8123/health/ready": context deadline exceeded

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I've followed the [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/create-k8s-cluster-with-aks-applicationgateway-ingress) and created a Kubernetes cluster in Azure. Below is the complete terraform code that I have used to built the Kubernetes cluster along with the AppGateway.

```
variable "resource_group_name_prefix" {
  default     = "rg"
  description = "Prefix of the resource group name that's combined with a random ID so name is unique in your Azure subscription."
}

variable "resource_group_location" {
  default     = "eastus"
  description = "Location of the resource group."
}

variable "virtual_network_name" {
  description = "Virtual network name"
  default     = "aksVirtualNetwork"
}

variable "virtual_network_address_prefix" {
  description = "VNET address prefix"
  default     = "192.168.0.0/16"
}

variable "aks_subnet_name" {
  description = "Subnet Name."
  default     = "kubesubnet"
}

variable "aks_subnet_address_prefix" {
  description = "Subnet address prefix."
  default     = "192.168.0.0/24"
}

variable "app_gateway_subnet_address_prefix" {
  description = "Subnet server IP address."
  default     = "192.168.1.0/24"
}

variable "app_gateway_name" {
  description = "Name of the Application Gateway"
  default     = "ApplicationGateway1"
}

variable "app_gateway_sku" {
  description = "Name of the Application Gateway SKU"
  default     = "Standard_v2"
}

variable "app_gateway_tier" {
  description = "Tier of the Application Gateway tier"
  default     = "Standard_v2"
}

variable "aks_name" {
  description = "AKS cluster name"
  default     = "aks-cluster1"
}
variable "aks_dns_prefix" {
  description = "Optional DNS prefix to use with hosted Kubernetes API server FQDN."
  default     = "aks"
}

variable "aks_agent_os_disk_size" {
  description = "Disk size (in GB) to provision for each of the agent pool nodes. This value ranges from 0 to 1023. Specifying 0 applies the default disk size for that agentVMSize."
  default     = 40
}

variable "aks_agent_count" {
  description = "The number of agent nodes for the cluster."
  default     = 1
}

variable "aks_agent_vm_size" {
  description = "VM size"
  default     = "Standard_B8ms"
}

variable "aks_service_cidr" {
  description = "CIDR notation IP range from which to assign service cluster IPs"
  default     = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

variable "aks_dns_service_ip" {
  description = "DNS server IP address"
  default     = "10.0.0.10"
}

variable "aks_docker_bridge_cidr" {
  description = "CIDR notation IP for Docker bridge."
  default     = "172.17.0.1/16"
}

variable "aks_enable_rbac" {
  description = "Enable RBAC on the AKS cluster. Defaults to false."
  default     = "false"
}

variable "vm_user_name" {
  description = "User name for the VM"
  default     = "vmuser1"
}

variable "public_ssh_key_path" {
  description = "Public key path for SSH."
  default     = "./keys/id_rsa.pub"
}

variable "tags" {
  type = map(string)

  default = {
    source = "terraform"
  }
}

# Locals block for hardcoded names
locals {
  backend_address_pool_name      = "${azurerm_virtual_network.test.name}-beap"
  frontend_port_name             = "${azurerm_virtual_network.test.name}-feport"
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.test.name}-feip"
  http_setting_name              = "${azurerm_virtual_network.test.name}-be-htst"
  listener_name                  = "${azurerm_virtual_network.test.name}-httplstn"
  request_routing_rule_name      = "${azurerm_virtual_network.test.name}-rqrt"
  app_gateway_subnet_name        = "appgwsubnet"
  subscription_id                = "<subscription_id>"  
  tenant_id                      = "<tenant_id>"
  client_id                      = "<client_id>"
  client_secret                  = "<client_secret>"
  client_objectid                = "<client_objectid>"
}

terraform {
  required_version = ">=0.12"

  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~>2.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = local.subscription_id
  tenant_id       = local.tenant_id
  client_id       = local.client_id
  client_secret   = local.client_secret

  features {}
}

resource "random_pet" "rg-name" {
  prefix = var.resource_group_name_prefix
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = random_pet.rg-name.id
  location = var.resource_group_location
}

# User Assigned Identities 
resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "testIdentity" {
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location

  name = "identity1"

  tags = var.tags
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "test" {
  name                = var.virtual_network_name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  address_space       = [var.virtual_network_address_prefix]

  subnet {
    name           = var.aks_subnet_name
    address_prefix = var.aks_subnet_address_prefix
  }

  subnet {
    name           = "appgwsubnet"
    address_prefix = var.app_gateway_subnet_address_prefix
  }

  tags = var.tags
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "kubesubnet" {
  name                 = var.aks_subnet_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.test.name
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  depends_on           = [azurerm_virtual_network.test]
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "appgwsubnet" {
  name                 = "appgwsubnet"
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.test.name
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  depends_on           = [azurerm_virtual_network.test]
}

# Public Ip 
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "test" {
  name                = "publicIp1"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku                 = "Standard"

  tags = var.tags
}

resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "network" {
  name                = var.app_gateway_name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location

  sku {
    name     = var.app_gateway_sku
    tier     = "Standard_v2"
    capacity = 2
  }

  gateway_ip_configuration {
    name      = "appGatewayIpConfig"
    subnet_id = data.azurerm_subnet.appgwsubnet.id
  }

  frontend_port {
    name = local.frontend_port_name
    port = 80
  }

  frontend_port {
    name = "httpsPort"
    port = 443
  }

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = local.frontend_ip_configuration_name
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.test.id
  }

  backend_address_pool {
    name = local.backend_address_pool_name
  }

  backend_http_settings {
    name                  = local.http_setting_name
    cookie_based_affinity = "Disabled"
    port                  = 80
    protocol              = "Http"
    request_timeout       = 1
  }

  http_listener {
    name                           = local.listener_name
    frontend_ip_configuration_name = local.frontend_ip_configuration_name
    frontend_port_name             = local.frontend_port_name
    protocol                       = "Http"
  }

  request_routing_rule {
    name                       = local.request_routing_rule_name
    rule_type                  = "Basic"
    http_listener_name         = local.listener_name
    backend_address_pool_name  = local.backend_address_pool_name
    backend_http_settings_name = local.http_setting_name
  }

  tags = var.tags

  depends_on = [azurerm_virtual_network.test, azurerm_public_ip.test]
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "k8s" {
  name       = var.aks_name
  location   = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  dns_prefix = var.aks_dns_prefix

  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  http_application_routing_enabled = false

  linux_profile {
    admin_username = var.vm_user_name

    ssh_key {
      key_data = file(var.public_ssh_key_path)
    }
  }

  default_node_pool {
    name            = "agentpool"
    node_count      = var.aks_agent_count
    vm_size         = var.aks_agent_vm_size
    os_disk_size_gb = var.aks_agent_os_disk_size
    vnet_subnet_id  = data.azurerm_subnet.kubesubnet.id
  }

  service_principal {
    client_id     = local.client_id
    client_secret = local.client_secret
  }

  network_profile {
    network_plugin     = "azure"
    dns_service_ip     = var.aks_dns_service_ip
    docker_bridge_cidr = var.aks_docker_bridge_cidr
    service_cidr       = var.aks_service_cidr
  }

  role_based_access_control {
    enabled = var.aks_enable_rbac
  }

  depends_on = [azurerm_virtual_network.test, azurerm_application_gateway.network]
  tags       = var.tags
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "ra1" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_subnet.kubesubnet.id
  role_definition_name = "Network Contributor"
  principal_id         = local.client_objectid

  depends_on = [azurerm_virtual_network.test]
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "ra2" {
  scope                = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.testIdentity.id
  role_definition_name = "Managed Identity Operator"
  principal_id         = local.client_objectid
  depends_on           = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.testIdentity]
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "ra3" {
  scope                = azurerm_application_gateway.network.id
  role_definition_name = "Contributor"
  principal_id         = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.testIdentity.principal_id
  depends_on           = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.testIdentity, azurerm_application_gateway.network]
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "ra4" {
  scope                = azurerm_resource_group.rg.id
  role_definition_name = "Reader"
  principal_id         = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.testIdentity.principal_id
  depends_on           = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.testIdentity, azurerm_application_gateway.network]
}
```

I have created the **id_rsa.pub** key like mentioned below

[image]

**AKS Cluster:**

[image]

**AppGateway:**

[image]

and I have installed the AGIC by running the following commands

```
az account set --subscription "Dev3-Tooling" 
az aks get-credentials --resource-group "rg-active-stag" --name "aks-cluster1"
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity/v1.8.6/deploy/infra/deployment.yaml --insecure-skip-tls-verify
helm repo add application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress https://appgwingress.blob.core.windows.net/ingress-azure-helm-package/
helm repo update
helm install ingress-azure  -f helm-config.yaml application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/ingress-azure  --version 1.5.0
```

Azure Ingress Pod is in the unhealthy state

[image]

[image]

and I am getting the following error while trying to access the application deployed

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I have tried to repro same in my lab environment and got below results.***

Step-1:

After provisioning kubernetes cluster and Application Gateway, connect to the cluster using the below command

```
$ az aks get-credentials -g <resourceGroupName> -n <cluster-name>
```

Step-2:

Install Azure AD Pod identity for token-based access control

Refer the below command, if your cluster is RBAC enabled.

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/azure/aad-pod-identity/master/deploy/infra/deployment-rbac.yaml"
```

Refer the below command, if your cluster is RBAC disabled.

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/azure/aad-pod-identity/master/deploy/infra/deployment.yaml
```

Step-3:

Add application gateway ingress controller to the helm repository.

```
`$helm repo add application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress https://appgwingress.blob.core.windows.net/ingress-azure-helm-package/

$helm repo update
```

Step-4

Now write helm configuration file and save it to helm-config.yaml as below.

```yaml
verbosityLevel: 3  
appgw:  
subscriptionId: <subscriptionId>  
resourceGroup: <resourceGroupName>  
name: <applicationGatewayName>  
shared: false  
armAuth:  
type: aadPodIdentity  
identityResourceID: <identityResourceId>  
identityClientID: <identityClientId>  
rbac:  
enabled: false # true/false  
aksClusterConfiguration:  
apiServerAddress: <aks-api-server-address>
```

Step-5:

Now, install AGIC using above file.

```
$helm install -f helm-config.yaml --generate-name application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/ingress-azure
```

After performing the above steps, you can verify ingress service using the below command.

```
$ kubectl get ingress
```

[image]
Access the IP address in above screenshot, you will be able to access the application.